# Pillow Image open save not working as expected

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I planing to use Pillow for a image processing application. i tried opening an image from pillow and saving to to test. but the image that was save is corrupt with noise.

```
from PIL import Image

i = Image.open('dot.jpg')
i.save('temp.jpg')
```

Original - [image: Original]

Saved - [image: Saved]

Comment: what is the format of the image in `path`? original and saved seem to be the same

Comment: it is a jpg image. yes they are same type

Comment: JPG is a compressed, lossy file format. You do not set any quality settings when saving so it uses the defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save it as `.png` format.
jpg format will result in some loss.

```
from PIL import Image

i = Image.open('dot.jpg')
i.save('temp.png')
```

Refer this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11603610/5774004)

Comment: Thank you. That Solved the problem